# Modify Default Sprint Backlog Query

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

We've recently added a new workflow state "Released" to both our product backlog item (PBI) and bug templates. Unfortunately, when a PBI or bug is marked "Released" it no longer appears in our default sprint queries. Is there a way to change the default sprint queries so that this new workflow is included? We're using TFS 2015.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant modify the Query, but you don't need to.

You do need to add that new State to the Process Configuration so that TFS knows what to do with it. You need to mapp the new state to one of the meta-states; "Proposed", "InProgress", or "Completed".

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/work/reference/process-configuration-xml-element#map

Once you have added the map work items should appear on the relevant board.